# Split a Single Subscription Stream into 2 Steams in Dart

Tags: dart, dart-async

I have a Stream of messages : some are requests, other are responses.
I would like to create 2 Streams from my source.

```
_responseStream = _sourceStream.transform(decoder).where((message) => message.isResponse());
_requestStream = _sourceStream.transform(decoder).where((message) => message.isRequest());
```

Is this solution optimized ? (in term of performance or other).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `_sourceStream` a broadcast stream? https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/streams#two-kinds-of-streams

Comment: Very good point, now I understand why I had metaphysical doubts on something that was somehow working. My mock  _sourceStream is broadcast, but it should not, I changed it to single subscription.
Now I'm even more interested in a snippet to convert a Single Subscription stream into 2 (Single Subscription) streams.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/async contains `StreamSplitter` that allows to do that.

```
final multiStream = StreamSplitter(_sourcStream.transform(decoder));
_responseStream = _multiStream.split().where((message) => message.isResponse());
_requestStream = _multiStream.split().where((message) => message.isRequest());
multiStream.close();
```

or

```
 final streams = StreamSplitter.splitFrom(_sourcStream.transform(decoder), 2); // 2 is the default and can be omitted
```